# Is there a way to create java objects from clojure maps?

Tags: clojure

is there a way to create java objects from Clojure maps? something where the following would hold - `(= my-map (bean (convert-to-object my-map)))`

Answer (score 2):

You would need to tell it what type of Java object you wanted to create. Take a look at the `org.clojure/java.data` Contrib library which can build Java objects from hash maps (via constructors, via property setters, via builders): https://github.com/clojure/java.data

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/uwcpdx/bean-dip

> Bidirectional translation between Clojure maps and Java beans that's
>   declarative and reflection-free